# 256 colors palette on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: command-line, games

I try to run a game in my terminal on Ubuntu 16.04, a game which was made using c ncurses library. At the time the game was finished, it had ran as I was expected in terminal. Then I've made some changes to a file (maybe .bashrc), such that I could use 256 color palette for my game.

Now, when I try to run the game I'm getting this error message:

> Error opening terminal: xterm-256color.

`TERM` variable is set to `xterm-256color` and tput colors output is 256. Is there a more appropriate method for testing if my terminal uses 256 colors with certainty and how can I solve the problem described above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no 100% reliable method for determining if a terminal **supports** a given number of colors.  You set `TERM` to tell applications to use a particular terminal description, so that ncurses and other libraries know how to work with the terminal.

The `xterm-256color` description is part of `ncurses-base`, an *essential* package:

```
$ dlocate /lib/terminfo/x/xterm-256color
ncurses-base: /lib/terminfo/x/xterm-256color
```

If your application cannot open it, that's likely because you have an environment variable set (such as `TERMINFO`) which tells ncurses to look in a place where that description does not exist.

You can use `strace` to see which files are opened by an application, and (usually) see problems of this sort, e.g., by looking for failed opens of "xterm-256color".

Further reading:

- [TERMINFO](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-TERMINFO), environment variable in the ncurses manual page

Comment: If I run in terminal the command "echo $TERMINFO" it outputs a blank row, so TERMINFO is not set. I don't understand this row from TERMINFO documentation, which says that the following directory might change the location where ncurses searches for my terminal info:  "the last directory to which ncurses wrote, if  any, is searched first." Something else, the TERMINFO_DIRS variable is not set, because it echos a blank row, too. Maybe I have to specify this too, I've programmed this game I'm trying to run on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: The output of the command that you've specified in your post is the same as yours.

Comment: I don't know how I didn't saw that you said to me to use STRACE command, because that is what I needed for seeing where ncurses searches for XTERM-256COLOR. I had to copy my xterm-256color compiled terminfo file from /lib/terminfo/x/ directory to /usr/share/terminfo/x directory. From then I can run my game, but after closing the game my prompt colors are changed. Surely I need to modify something into an env variable. At least I can run the game. Thank you for help!